# Lualatex and mathtools warnings

Tags: luatex, mathtools

I just moved from PDFlatex to Lualatex and I have warnig messages after compilation.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,french]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage[scale={0.75,0.8},footskip=1.5cm,heightrounded]{geometry}


\begin{document}
    $\alpha+\Gamma=a+X$
    
    $\bm{x}$
\end{document}
```

And here are the warnings I get after compilation:

```
Package unicode-math Warning: Using \overbracket and \underbracket from
(unicode-math)                `mathtools' package.
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                 Use \Uoverbracket and \Uunderbracket for
(unicode-math)                original `unicode-math' definition.


Package unicode-math Warning: I'm going to overwrite the following commands
(unicode-math)                from the `mathtools' package: 
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                     \dblcolon, \coloneqq, \Coloneqq, \eqqcolon.
(unicode-math)                
(unicode-math)                 
(unicode-math)                 Note that since I won't overwrite the other
(unicode-math)                colon-like commands, using them will lead to
(unicode-math)                inconsistencies.
```

So what should I do to get rid off these warnings?